# Powerpoint: change keyboard shortcut to view current slide

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

How do I change (or add) the keyboard shortcut (currently shift-f5), e.g. to f1, for viewing the current slide?

My workflow:

- I go over the slides in slide-show mode.
- When I need to modify a slide, I press ESC, change it, and then need a quick key press (f1) to go back to slide-show mode.

---

I've just noticed something: instead of ESC, I can alt-tab to the editor. The slide show would be updated as well. However, the editor doesn't show the current slide in the slide show, so it's good only if you have multiple changes for the same slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than by installing a program that overrides Windows/application keyboard shortcuts, you can't do this. PowerPoint doesn't provide the ability customized shortcuts.

Comment: Pretty lame to remove such a basic feature, considering their poor choice for shortcuts.

Comment: Removing such a basic feature might have been lame, true, but that's not the case. The feature was never there.